# Find a,b and c. Any method?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that $$\frac{1}{a+\frac{1}{b+\frac{1}{c+1}}}=\frac{16}{38}$$, find $a,b,c$.

I've been figuring for this quite some time? Is it possible to solve?

Comment: Are there any constraints on $a,b$ and $c$? For example, are they assumed to be natural numbers?

Comment: You have enough reputation that it seems incredible you wouldn't know to show some context, work and ideas for a question. What have you tried? What is making this hard for you?

Comment: (Please don't close this. I find it interesting.)

Comment: @goblin Without context it's annoying rather then interesting. Assuming no constraints on a,b,c it trivially has infinitely many solutions. Given the constraint you propose it would become interesting.

Comment: @DRF, sure, but this thing looks like a [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction); perhaps the OP thought it was obvious what he meant.

Comment: @goblin I didn't vote to close, but I understand the reasoning. The OP or someone else should add context to make the question sensible.

Answer (score 2):

This is a "continued fraction," and there are standard ways of computing them.  To get you started,

$$\frac{16}{38} = \frac{1}{\frac{38}{16}} = \frac{1}{2+\frac{3}{8}}. $$

So $a=2$.  Continue in this fashion with $\frac{3}{8}$.   Wiki "continued fraction" for (tons) more information.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution  ; sorry for hand writing 
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{a+\frac{1}{b+\frac{1}{c+1}}}&=\frac{16}{38}\\
a+\frac{1}{b+\frac{1}{c+1}}&=\frac{38}{16}= 2+\frac{3}{8}\\
\text{So}\quad      a=2\\
\frac{1}{b+\frac{1}{c+1}}&=\frac{3}{8}\\
b+\frac{1}{c+1}&=\frac{8}{3}=2+\frac{2}{3}\\
\text{So}\quad     b=2\\
\frac{1}{c+1}&=\frac{2}{3}\\
c+1=\frac{3}{2}=1+\frac{1}{2}\\
\text{So}\quad     c=\frac{1}{2}\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: -1 While you do keep the equivalences in the correct places the answer is extremely misleading making it seem as if there is a unique solution.

Comment: @DRF   I  say "a solution" ;  not "the solution "

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is, but you'll end up with infinite possibilities:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{a+\frac{1}{b+\frac{1}{c+1}}}&=\frac{16}{38}\\
a+\frac{1}{b+\frac{1}{c+1}}&=\frac{38}{16}\\
\frac{1}{b+\frac{1}{c+1}}&=\frac{38-16a}{16}\\
b+\frac{1}{c+1}&=\frac{16}{38-16a}\\
\frac{1}{c+1}&=\frac{16-(38-16a)b}{38-16a}\\
c&=\frac{38-16a}{16-(38-16a)b}-1
\end{align*}$$
You can chose $a$ and $b$ freely, and then $c$ will be determined by the two.